# Number of collections of books

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 5 maths books,4 science books and 3 literature books and books in a particular category are considered different.

If I have to make collections of books out of them with at least one book of each category has to be included in any collection,then consider below two solutions:

1. straight forward way: $$(2^5-1) * (2^4-1) * (2^3-1) = 3255$$
2. Now i will first get "must one book for each category" books followed by possible total collection of remaining 9 different books:

   $${5\choose 1}*{4 \choose 1}*{3\choose 1}* 2^9 = 30720$$

Giving an example for 2nd solution:

Suppose the books are M1,M2,M3,M4,M5, S1,S2,S3,S4 and L1,L2,L3.

Now i can take 1 book from each category in $${5\choose 1}*{4 \choose 1}*{3\choose 1}$$ and lets say that is M2,S4,L3 and my remaining books are [M1,M3,M4,M5, S1,S2,S3, L1,L2] which are nine in number. Now from this list the total number of collections possible are $${9\choose 0}+{9 \choose 1}+ ....+{9\choose 9} = 2^9$$

I am certainly sure my first solution works, what's the problem with second solution?

Comment: Situations where you take, say, two math books, X and Y, get counted under X being the must book and again under Y being the must book.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: I don't see a problem in the first answer. It seems correct (and Gerry Myerson's explanation why the second one is wrong is also correct and could be turned into an answer in my view). $2^n-1$ counts all subsets of $n$ objects except for the empty subset, the only one being excluded here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you please elaborate your explanation?

Comment: Regarding your second answer, I don't understand where the $2^9$ comes from. Aside from that, it is incorrect because it assumes a selection of a 1 book at most from each category. Since you allow more than 1 selection from each category, the 2nd answer is incorrect.

Comment: @EmmadKareem edited and given an example

Comment: The way you derived the $2^9$ is correct when you want to select "1 book, or 2 books or 3 books, etc. from a set of 9 books with returning the selected books every time (that is why 9 is constant) " - This scenario has nothing to do with the problem you have.

Comment: Consider the selection M2, S4, L3, M1. Your first method counts that selection once, which is what you want. But your second method counts it twice: once as first select M2, S4, L3, and then from the remaining 9 books take M1, and then a second time as first select M1, S4, L3, and then from the remaining 9 books select M2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Got it! multiple counting same selections ... thanks

Comment: Good! Now, let me encourage you to write up your understanding of the situation and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below two possible collections:

Collection 1:  Let must have books be M1,S1,L1, and one out of other possible 2^9 choices may be say M2,S2,L2

Collection 2:  Let must have books be M2,S2,L2, and one out of other possible 2^9 choices may be M1,S1,L1

But the above two collections are one and the same which is {M1,M2,S1,S2,L1,L2}, but counted twice and hence the second solution in the question asked is ultimately wrong!